# SpringBoot fails to find Mongo Repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem where I am trying to add a second mongo database to my app. I am doing so by adding a second MongoTemplate that uses a config prefix and then a specific bean name.

I have an AbstractMongoConfig like so

```
public abstract class AbstractMongoConfig {
    private String uri;

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI(uri));
    }

    abstract public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() throws Exception;                                                                        }
```

Which I extend into a specific template config like this... To add another mongo DB I would add another one of these and then annotate different repositories to use a different config via the templateRef, right?

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="server.mongodb")
public class ServerMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfig {
    @Primary
    @Override
    @Bean(name="serverMongoTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

With this, I should be able to put configs like server.mongodb.uri=...

I have a repo that uses this

```
@Repository
public interface MAPRepository extends MongoRepository<MAP, String> {
    public List<MAP> findByName(String name);
}
```

And the entity

```
@Document(collection="maptest")
public class MAP {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

I then have a service class that uses this repo

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(mongoTemplateRef="serverMongoTemplate")
@Service
public class TestService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "serverMongoTemplate")
    private MAPRepository mrepo;

    ... use mrepo ...
}
```

But when starting this up I get an error

```
Description:

Field mrepo in testpkg.svc.TestHandler required a bean of type 'testpkg.repo.MAPRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'testpkg.repo.MAPRepository' in your configuration.
```

and lower ...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'testpkg.repo.MAPRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=serverMongoTemplate)}
```

The service is in a different package than the repository but I have checked the imports and all that... it all matches just fine. THe MAPRepository is annotated with @Repository which means it should be available as a bean, right?

What else might be going on here that is causing this to not see the bean? Is there some class I can turn debug on to figure out what's going on?

Before I added the ServerMongoConfig thing, it worked fine. It was able to write to that DB without a problem. Just now it can't instantiate it properly.

Comment: Why do you have `@Qualifier(value = "serverMongoTemplate")` on your `private MAPRepository mrepo;`

Comment: I was just trying anything... it seems to have no effect

Comment: And `@EnableMongoRepositories(mongoTemplateRef="serverMongoTemplate")` should be on  a class annoted with `@Configuration` not on `@Service` which is used to declare a bean

Comment: If I put all of the service, repo, etc all in the same package it works and those `@EnableMongoRepositories` and `@Qualifier` seem to have an effect on which template it uses.

Comment: I think you mis configured your project. The ˋ@SpringBootApplication` annotated class should be in the root package, so all beans and configuration classes will be discovered, and usually we put all ˋ@Enable...` annotation in that class for clarity.

Comment: The `@SpringBootApplication` is in the Application class which is at the root. The MongoTemplate is chosen by the `@Qualifier` or `@Enable...` annotations as per: http://java.amitph.com/2015/06/multiple-mongo-templates-in-spring-boot.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be that the @EnableMongoRepositories needs to have a basePackages that refers to the proper package that contains the new template otherwise I guess mongoTemplateRef can't properly find it.

So, on the service class:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages={"testpkg.repo"}, mongoTemplateRef="serverMongoTemplate")
```

and it all works fine.